# Regular expression to validate image path with Hebew, English and characters

Tags: php, regex, character, hebrew

I have image path's like

```
טוסטר.jpeg
טוסטר(243).jpeg
טוסטר_234.jpeg
justImage.jpeg
justImage(2).jpeg
justImage_32.jpeg
justImage-12.jpeg
justImage-טר.jpeg
_asd_טוסטר_234.jpeg
/w/a/טוסטר.jpeg
/w/a/טוסטר_234.jpeg
/w/a/טוסטר(243).jpeg
```

I need to pass the validation for such data. In the path allowed an image extension(no need to validate the exact extensions), underscore, dots, brackets, English chars, digits. An image can have a path like /a/b/someImageName.ext

I made only this regex, but it only validates one Hebrew char and not the whole string

`#[-\w.\\\\/()]+$)|((?:\p{Hebrew}+|\w+)+?)#`

this regex works perfectly with English and all cases which I need, but when adds the Hebrew doesn't work well

`#[-\w.\\/()]+$)#`

example

https://regex101.com/r/7bndbF/1

thx in advance

Comment: `#[-\w.\\/()]+$)#` is a malformed pattern, how can it work? Try `preg_match('#[-\w.\\\\/()]+$#uD', $str)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew added explain to regex how it works

Comment: `(^(?!.*[\\/]\.{2}[\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\/])[-\w.\\/()]+$)` is not `#[-\w.\\/()]+$)#`, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right, not sure why you see that, because I pasted this but didn't publish the `(^(?!.*[\\/]\.{2}[\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\/])[-\w.\\/()]+$)`, only `#[-\w.\\/()]+$)#`

Comment: Ok, so does `'#^(?!.*[\\\\/]\.{2}[\\\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\\\/])[-\w.\\\\/()]+$#uD'` work for you?

Comment: nope, only one Hebrew char is highlighted https://regex101.com/r/WOINfy/1

Comment: No, see the MATCH pane on the right. All chars are matched. The highlighting feature is buggy in the regex101.com. Use the code I supplied in PHP, not in online regex testers that you do not know how to use.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems like works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
preg_match('#^(?!.*[\\\\/]\.{2}[\\\\/])(?!\.{2}[\\\\/])[-\w.\\\\/()]+$#uD', $string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WOINfy/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*[\\/]\.{2}[\\/])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `\` or `/`, two dots and a `\` or `/` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?!\.{2}[\\/])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are two dots and `/` or `\` immediately to the right of the current location
- `[-\w.\\/()]+` - zero or more `-`, letters, digits, `_`, `.`, `/`, `\`, `(` and `)` chars (any Unicode letters and digits are allowed due to `u` modifier)
- `$` - the very end of string (due to the `D` modifier, no trailing newline is allowed.)

Answer (score 0):

You missed the unicode modifier (and the opening `(` of the first group) in your pattern. with it.

```
$pattern = '(^(/?[\p{Hebrew}\p{Latin}\pN()_.-]+)+$)uD';
```

#### Pattern Details

- `^` start of string
- `(` group 1 start

  - `/?` one or no `/`
  - `[` character class start

    - `\p{Hebrew}` Hebrew script
    - `\p{Latin}` Latin script
    - `\pN` Numeric chars (any script)
    - `()_.-` specific chars
  - `]` character class end
  - `+` at least one
- `)` group 1 end
- `+` at least one
- `$`

#### Modifiers

- `u` unicode (utf-8) mode
- `D` do not allow `$` to match `\n` at string end

If you don't need to be that specific you could replace the scripts with `\pL` (letter).

```
$pattern = '(^(/?[\pL\pN()_.-]+)+$)Du';
```